# Select all rows excluding a specific month and year combination in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata, where-clause

[This is the table from which](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C1Al.png) 
I want to SELECT all the rows excluding the year 2005 and the month 3.
I tried `WHERE year_num = 2005 AND month_num = 3` but it excludes all the rows which have year as 2005.

Comment: `WHERE (year_num, month_num) NOT IN ((2005, 3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT`:

```
where not (year_num = 2005 and month_num = 3)
```

Or:

```
where year_num <> 2005 or month_num <> 3
```

Note:  Both of these also filter `NULL` values, but can be easily modified to fix that (if the columns can be `NULL`).